# How to get Http Status Code and Vourbose logs by Curl function

Tags: bash, shell, curl

We try to check the API connection and response by several curl commands as follows, we have two issue though.

```
-- function
function exec_cmd() {
cmd=$@
echo "curl command：" ${cmd}
response=$(${cmd} --max-time ${timeout_sec} -o ${LogFile} -w '%{http_code}\n' -S)
echo statud_code：${response}
}

-- curl command#1 ...
exec_cmd curl -v -x put <LBFrontIP/ApiEndpoint1> -H 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'Host:<HostName>' -d '{"SystemId":"XXXX", "AppNo":"99999999999"}'

-- curl command#2
exec_cmd curl -v -x put <LBFrontIP/ApiEndpoint2> -H 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'Host:<HostName>' -d '{"sbSystemId":"XXXX", "email":"XXX@example.com", 
"PhoneNo":"99999999999"}'

-- curl command#3
exec_cmd curl -v -x put <LBFrontIP/ApiEndpoint3> -H 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'Host:<HostName>' -d '
{
    "ID1": "XXXXX",
    "ID2": "1q2w3e4r5t",
    "applyNo": "00db182faef74e779ca958681127bcec", ...
    "docLiveScore": "0.1391"
}'
```

Issue #1 : cmd=$@ can get the curl command but if that curl command contains @ or return code, it can't work as expected.
curl command#1 is working fine, but curl command#2 and #3 is not, since bash misunderstands @ and return code in data option as terminate of the command line. Curl command can work by itself though.
Also tried cmd=$* or cmd="$@" but not working so far.

Issue #2 : We'd like to get status_code for our quick check, but on the same time, we'd like to get the detail response in the log.
Is there any better way to get both of status_code and verbose log by appropriate function?

Above commands over write the verbose logs...

Comment: Suggestions: 1) check syntax on shellcheck.net and fix everything. 2) move `curl -v -x put...` and its static options inside the function and pass dynamic values as arguments `exec_cmd "val1" "val2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the complexity of the commands involved, I am tempted to say that you should avoid command parsing and read the command lines from a job configuration file.

```
#!/bin/bash

START=`pwd`
echo ${START}
BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
ThisDATE=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S' `

LogPrefix="${START}/${BASE}.${ThisDATE}"        ; rm -f "${LogPrefix}"*
BatchFile="${START}/${BASE}.${ThisDATE}.config"     ; rm -f "${BatchFile}"

cat >$BatchFile <<-!EnDoFbAtCh
curl -v -x put <LBFrontIP/ApiEndpoint1> -H 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'Host:<HostName>' -d '{"SystemId":"XXXX", "AppNo":"99999999999"}'
curl -v -x put <LBFrontIP/ApiEndpoint2> -H 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'Host:<HostName>' -d '{"sbSystemId":"XXXX", "email":"XXX@example.com", "PhoneNo":"99999999999"}'
curl -v -x put <LBFrontIP/ApiEndpoint3> -H 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'Host:<HostName>' -d '{ "ID1": "XXXXX", "ID2": "1q2w3e4r5t", "applyNo": "00db182faef74e779ca958681127bcec", ...  "docLiveScore": "0.1391" }'
!EnDoFbAtCh

function exec_cmd() {
    echo "curl command： ${cmd}"
    ${cmd} --max-time ${timeout_sec} -o ${LogFile} -w '%{http_code}\n' -S
    RC=$?
    echo "statud_code：${RC}"
}

index=1
while read cmd
do
    if [ -z "${cmd}" ] ; then  break ; fi

    LogFile="${LogPrefix}.${index}.log"

    exec_cmd

    index=`expr ${index} + 1 `
done < "${BatchFile}"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your beatiful code, Eric. It's really practical and solve my two issues. I really appreciated all of your consideration :)